# Округление числа в большую строну в sql

Tags: c#, sql

Подскажите, как округлить число в большую сторону? Существует ли в `sql` функция, аналогичная функции из `C# Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`
Т.е. если я имею `7.5`, я должен получить `8`, но если имею `7.4`, то должен получит `7`.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `0.5` к числу перед округлением.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, округлением с помощью round?

Comment: select round(5.4, 0);// получите 5
select round(5.5, 0);// получите 6

Comment: Не работает, если через запятую 0

Comment: Что значит округлить в большую, если вы пишите что **7.4** должно округлиться до **7**?

Comment: При значении c дробной частью 0.5 округлять вперёд, а не назад.

Comment: Ну дак **округление в большую сторону** это округление до ближайшего целого большего заданного числа, то есть 7.1, 7.4, 7.5, 7.9, все округляются до 8. А то что вы пишите, это обычное классическое округление в математике. Есть еще часто в функциях округление вариант банковского округления, когда округляется к ближайшему четному, когда **2.7 => 2**, а **3.1 => 4**

Comment: 7.5 округляется в большую т.е. до 8 с 0 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/358781/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select round(7.5, 0) from dual

Comment: Попробовал Ваш вариант, в Management Studio, действительно работает. Но в Access-е почему-то такой трюк не проходит.

Comment: @PyrejkeeПурешкин указывайте в тэгах к вопросу какую СУБД используете. [В Access функция `round`](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/round.php) выполняет банковское округление, про которое я писал в комментариях.

Comment: Хорошо, возьму на заметку. Думал язык SQL унифицирован.

Answer (score 2):

В Access можно сделать так:

```
SELECT round(x+0.05,0)
```